# Is it possible to create a list of pie charts with future builder?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a list of pie charts that would present a monthly report so is it possible to generate a pie chart for every month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [pie_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart) package for this. You can look here for example:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

// Sets a platform override for desktop to avoid exceptions. See
// https://flutter.dev/desktop#target-platform-override for more info.
void enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop() {
  if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux)) {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  }
}

void main() {
  enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Pie Chart Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

enum LegendShape { Circle, Rectangle }

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Map<String, double> dataMap = {
    "Flutter": 5,
    "React": 3,
    "Xamarin": 2,
    "Ionic": 2,
  };
  List<Color> colorList = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.yellow,
  ];

  ChartType _chartType = ChartType.disc;
  bool _showCenterText = true;
  double _ringStrokeWidth = 32;
  double _chartLegendSpacing = 32;

  bool _showLegendsInRow = false;
  bool _showLegends = true;

  bool _showChartValueBackground = true;
  bool _showChartValues = true;
  bool _showChartValuesInPercentage = false;
  bool _showChartValuesOutside = false;

  LegendShape _legendShape = LegendShape.Circle;
  LegendPosition _legendPosition = LegendPosition.right;

  int key = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final chart = PieChart(
      key: ValueKey(key),
      dataMap: dataMap,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      chartLegendSpacing: _chartLegendSpacing,
      chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2 > 300
          ? 300
          : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
      colorList: colorList,
      initialAngleInDegree: 0,
      chartType: _chartType,
      centerText: _showCenterText ? "HYBRID" : null,
      legendOptions: LegendOptions(
        showLegendsInRow: _showLegendsInRow,
        legendPosition: _legendPosition,
        showLegends: _showLegends,
        legendShape: _legendShape == LegendShape.Circle
            ? BoxShape.circle
            : BoxShape.rectangle,
        legendTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      chartValuesOptions: ChartValuesOptions(
        showChartValueBackground: _showChartValueBackground,
        showChartValues: _showChartValues,
        showChartValuesInPercentage: _showChartValuesInPercentage,
        showChartValuesOutside: _showChartValuesOutside,
      ),
      ringStrokeWidth: _ringStrokeWidth,
    );
    final settings = SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Pie Chart Options'.toUpperCase(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.overline.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("chartType"),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: DropdownButton<ChartType>(
                  value: _chartType,
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("disc"),
                      value: ChartType.disc,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("ring"),
                      value: ChartType.ring,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _chartType = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("ringStrokeWidth"),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: DropdownButton<double>(
                  value: _ringStrokeWidth,
                  disabledHint: Text("select chartType.ring"),
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("16"),
                      value: 16,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("32"),
                      value: 32,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("48"),
                      value: 48,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (_chartType == ChartType.ring)
                      ? (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            _ringStrokeWidth = val;
                          });
                        }
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showCenterText,
              title: Text("showCenterText"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showCenterText = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("chartLegendSpacing"),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: DropdownButton<double>(
                  value: _chartLegendSpacing,
                  disabledHint: Text("select chartType.ring"),
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("16"),
                      value: 16,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("32"),
                      value: 32,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("48"),
                      value: 48,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("64"),
                      value: 64,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _chartLegendSpacing = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Legend Options'.toUpperCase(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.overline.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showLegendsInRow,
              title: Text("showLegendsInRow"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showLegendsInRow = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showLegends,
              title: Text("showLegends"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showLegends = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("legendShape"),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: DropdownButton<LegendShape>(
                  value: _legendShape,
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("BoxShape.circle"),
                      value: LegendShape.Circle,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("BoxShape.rectangle"),
                      value: LegendShape.Rectangle,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _legendShape = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("legendPosition"),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: DropdownButton<LegendPosition>(
                  value: _legendPosition,
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("left"),
                      value: LegendPosition.left,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("right"),
                      value: LegendPosition.right,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("top"),
                      value: LegendPosition.top,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("bottom"),
                      value: LegendPosition.bottom,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _legendPosition = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Chart values Options'.toUpperCase(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.overline.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showChartValueBackground,
              title: Text("showChartValueBackground"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showChartValueBackground = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showChartValues,
              title: Text("showChartValues"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showChartValues = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showChartValuesInPercentage,
              title: Text("showChartValuesInPercentage"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showChartValuesInPercentage = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _showChartValuesOutside,
              title: Text("showChartValuesOutside"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _showChartValuesOutside = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Pie Chart @apgapg"),
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                key = key + 1;
              });
            },
            child: Text("Reload".toUpperCase()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (_, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth >= 600) {
            return Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: chart,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: settings,
                )
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: chart,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 32,
                    ),
                  ),
                  settings,
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ohh this pie chart seems simpler than fl_Chart thanks man I'll give it a try

Comment: If the answer is helped you, you can accept it and upvote :)